# Reduce object thought object.entries

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have this kind of object

I want to get new object with keys that have "exist === true"

```js
const someObj  = {
      super: {
        exist: true
      },
      photo: {
        exist: true
      },
      request: {
        exist: false
      }
}
const newObj = Object.entries(someObj).reduce((newObj, [key, val]) => {
  if (this.key.exist) { // how to check "exist" is true ?
    return { ...newObj, [key]: val }
  }
}, {});

console.log(newObj);
```

Comment: `this[key].exist`

Comment: thank you for answer, I realized I could just use `val.exist`

Comment: Checked the post to resolve the es-lint issue, and got it fixed. Thanks

Comment: @JonasWilms I'm not sure how this question is duplicate with the one referenced. Could you, please, explain to me?

Comment: @GerardoLima indeed that duplicate wasn't really one, seems I've missread the question back then. FWIW the question actually has working code, it's just missing a `return newObj` in the `else` case, so actually should've been closed as "not reproducible as a typo" ...

Comment: @JonasWilms besides that, the question had another error, trying to access `this.key.exist`, instead of `val.exist`. There were silly bugs -- it happens to all -- and @NarendraJadhav found them and fixed. My comments are just to point that the contents here helped me to find solution to a problem, but I almost dismissed, because of the duplicate mark. cheers

Answer (score 26):

You can be achieve your required result by following code

**DEMO**

```js
const someObj = {
  super: {
    exist: true
  },
  photo: {
    exist: true
  },
  request: {
    exist: false
  }
};
const newObj = Object.entries(someObj).reduce((newObj, [key, val]) => {
  if (val.exist) {
    newObj[key] = val;
  }
  return newObj;
}, {})

console.log(newObj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {  max-height: 100% !important;  top: 0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to filter the entries and then create a new object with `Object.fromEntries` like so:

```js
const someObj = {
super: {
    exist: true
},
photo: {
    exist: true
},
request: {
    exist: false
}
};

const filtered = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(someObj).filter(([, value]) => value.exist))

console.log(filtered)
```